# Are language packs still available for Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, language, language-pack

I want to use Windows XP in a language (Mapudungun) which [was supported in XP](http://mapudunguyu.blogspot.co.uk/2009/04/windows-en-mapudungun.html) but not longer supported in further editions of Windows. For that I plan to install Windows XP using Virtual Box in my Ubuntu machine.

However, XP is no longer maintained. As such, I only want to do this if I can get access to such language package. I cannot find anything about language packs for Windows XP in the official Windows website. In fact, most of XP stuff are unavailable now.

Anyone know something about this? Any user with a current installation of XP? Are XP languages still available to download?

Comment: They can be found on the internet. Use at your own risk.